# getopt doesn't support spaces between options in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, getopt

So my getopt code looks like this:

```
    ARG_H=0
    ARG_V=0
    ARG_A=0
    ARG_N=5

    TEMP=`getopt -o hvn:a -n "vdu" -- "$1"`
    eval set -- "$TEMP"
    while true ; do
            case "$1" in
                    -h|--argh) ARG_H=1 ; shift ;;
                    -v|--argv) ARG_V=1 ; shift ;;
                    -n|--argn)
                            case "$2" in
                            "") shift 2 ;;
                            *) ARG_N=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
                            esac ;;
                    -a|--arga) ARG_A=1 ; shift ;;
                    --) shift ; break ;;
                    *) echo "error" ; exit 1 ;;
            esac
    done
    echo "$ARG_H"
    echo "$ARG_V"
    echo "$ARG_N"
    echo "$ARG_A"
```

But for some reason, it only works if my command line looks like this:

```
./vdu -a-v-n15
```

or

```
./vdu -avn15
```

but if I type in

```
./vdu -a -v -n 15
```

it will only register the first flag. Why is this? This code seems to be identical to the getopts tutorials I've been looking at.

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMP=`getopt -o hvn:a -n "vdu" -- "$1"`
```

`$1` is just the first argument to your program. Use `$@` to pass all the arguments.

```
TEMP=`getopt -o hvn:a -n "vdu" -- "$@"`
```

Other thoughts:

- It is traditional to pass `$0` to `-n` rather than hardcoding the program name.
- You could skip the temporary variable if you combine the `eval set` with the `getopt` call.
- It's considered good style to use `$(...)` in place of `` `...` ``. `$(...)` can be nested more easily.

Result:

```
eval set -- "$(getopt -o hvn:a -n "$0" -- "$@")"
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I thought since I was doing this inside a function, that I had to pass $@ in as an argument and use $! in the getopt command, which apparently isn't the case.